# Instruct JavaScript's Date to read a date string dd/mm/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date, format

I would like to parse the date string `01/04/2022` as **April 1st** and **not** like **January 4th** by JavaScript Date().

Is there any way I can force/instruct javascript's `Date()` to read a date string as `dd/mm/yyyy` and not as `mm/dd/yyyy`?

```
new Date('01/04/2022') // returns Tue Jan 04 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can add your custom method to date object, using protype.

Comment: javascript was written by an American, so you get what you get

Comment: @p4avinash why would you infect the Date **prototype**? it's too late to do anything in the prototype

Comment: @Bravo Well, either we've to format the string before passing it in the date object or we've to add our method to date object. To make javascript parse in mm/dd/yyyy format. I can't think of any other solution. If you have then, enlighten me. I'd be glad to know about some new approach.

Comment: @p4avinash you don't use the prototype, a prototype has functions for date instances - it's too late to parse a string to a date instance in a date instance .... you'd just make a function ... you could add it to the `Date` object for convenience, but not the date **prototype** for the aforementioned reasons

Comment: @p4avinash - will you look at that - stackoverflow doesn't break my code

Comment: @Bravo yes, i apologize for my mistake. I've removed my answer which was wrong. And thanks for the answer. I found out my mistake. Also a lesson learned. No hate.. bro

Comment: me no hate noone - I'm a Date nerd from the 90's - I wrote a single line formula to get the day of the week from a date using just arithmetic - I know a thing or two about dates :p

Answer (score 1):

It's quite trivial to create a function to do the job

```js
const dmy = s => new Date(...s.split(/\D+/).reverse().map((v,i)=>+v-(i%2)))
console.log(dmy('01/04/2022').toString())
```

You could add it to `Date` ... so you always know where to find it

```js
Date.dmy = s => new Date(...s.split(/\D+/).reverse().map((v,i)=>+v-(i%2)))
console.log(Date.dmy('01/04/2022').toString())
console.log(Date.dmy('01/13/2022').toString()) // oops, didn't fail
```

however, the above won't fail on an invalid date

To do so, write it like this

```js
Date.dmy = s => {
    const a = s.split('/');
    return new Date(`${a[1]}/${a[0]}/${a[2]}`);
}
console.log(Date.dmy('01/04/2022').toString())
console.log(Date.dmy('01/13/2022').toString())
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the french formating :

```
const start = Date.now();
const date = new Date(start);
const formatted = date.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR")
```

Comment: parsing is input, not output - `'01/04/2022'` is an input to date constructor interpreted as m/d/y ... OP wants it to be interpreted as d/m/y for the purposes of constructing a new date object

Answer (score -2):

The solution may be a string hope the below code helps:

```js
let day = new Date().getDate()
let months = new Date().getMonth();
let year = new Date().getFullYear();

const formatDate = (day, months, year) =>{
    let total = ""
    let error = false
    let errorMessage = ""
    if(day != null && months != null && year != null){
        error = false
        if(months <= 9){
            total = `0${day}/0${months}/${year}`
        }else{
            total = `0${day}/${months}/${year}`;
        }
    }else{
        error = true
        errorMessage = "ERROR, in day, month, or year"
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total
}

// Calling Function
console.log(formatDate(day, months, year))
```

Comment: dear lord, today is the 7th of march according to your code ... again ... OP wants to parse a string in dd/mm/yyyy format, not output one